# MPI deadlock runtime error

Tags: c++, многопоточность, mpi

Здравствуйте, в работе с mpi возникла такая проблема:

```
std::vector<int> sender(world_size,0);
for(int j =0;j<world_size;++j){
    for (int i =0 ;i < world_size;++i) {
        int rank = j + pow(2,i);
        if (rank<world_size) {
            sender[rank] = j;
        }
    }

}

if(world_rank!=0) {
    MPI_Status status,main_status;
    MPI_Probe(0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &number_amount);
    int number_buf = 0;
    printf("Process %d received ready for starting\n",world_rank);
    MPI_Recv(&number_buf, number_amount, MPI_INT, sender[world_rank], 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
             &main_status);
    printf("11Process %d received number %d from process %d\n",world_rank,
           number_buf,main_status.MPI_SOURCE);

}

for(int i =1;i<world_size;++i) {
    if (world_rank == sender[i]) {
        MPI_Send(&i, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("0 thread %d send\n", sender[i]);

    }
}
```

Запуская на 4х машинах, должно работать так:

процессы 1 2 3 ждут получения

процесс 0 посылает сообщения 1 2, и затем 3 должен принять от 1го, но после получения первым, он не может отправить 3ему, а тот принять и все падает, я не могу выявить ошибку. (irecv/isend) не помогают.